# How to make Missing[] invariant for some functions without redefining them

Tags: replacement

[Missing[...]](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing.html) "is a symbolic object, with no default evaluation rules defined."

Missing data can be tagged and enables use of filters like [DeleteMissing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteMissing.html). So it's worthwhile to normalize various types of missing values, like "" or "NA" to `Missing[...]`.

EDIT:

Suppose a set of functions `{foo,bar}` are interatively applied a data column that contains `Missing[]` elements.

Unless the `{foo,bar}` are implemented to handle Missing, increasingly long unevaluated expressions `bar[foo[Missing[]]` are generated, which often throw `Dataset` Failures.

Is there a global way to make `Missing[]` invariant, ie `f[m_Missing]` --> `m`, for any `f` without actually overloading `f` on _Missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow your example so I'll focus on your summary line:

> Is there a global way to make `Missing[]` invariant, ie `f[m_Missing]` --> `m`, for any `f` without actually overloading `f` on _Missing?

That is a job for UpValues, i.e. definitions made with [`UpSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpSet.html), [`UpSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpSetDelayed.html), [`TagSet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagSet.html), etc.:

```
Unprotect[Missing];

_[m_Missing] ^:= m

Protect[Missing];
```

Now:

```
foo[Missing[]]

bar[Missing["NotAvailable"]]
```

> ```
> Missing[]
>
> Missing["NotAvailable"]
> ```

Or:

```
Print /@ {1, 2, 3, Missing[], 5};
```

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 5

---

Taliesin Beynon raises an important concern in the comments: this raw method will probably break stuff.  However I chose to technically answer the question as asked rather than worry about its implications.

You can restrict the pattern however you see fit, within the limitations of *Mathematica*, but since I saw no domain clearly delineated in the question I saw no point in proceeding.

*Merely as an example* we could strip only `` Global` `` heads:

```
Unprotect[Missing];

h_[m_Missing] /; ! StringFreeQ[Context@h, "Global`"] ^:= m

Protect[Missing];
```

Now:

```
{Missing[]}

Plus[1, Missing[], 2]
```

> ```
> {Missing[]}
>
> 3 + Missing[]
> ```

Yet:

```
foo[Missing[]]

bar[Missing["NotAvailable"]]
```

> ```
> Missing[]
>
> Missing["NotAvailable"]
> ```

Again this is not intended for use; it is only an example.  If you precisely define the behavior you want I can attempt to help you implement it.

Comment: That technique is at high risk of causing bizarre breakages, because, for example, `{Missing[]}` will rewrite itself as `Missing[]`. `Missing[]` is a perfectly good expression, it is context-dependent whether it should be propagated through a function.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon Okay, that's a good point, but isn't this what the OP requested?  Since you seem to have a better understanding of the request what context do you speak of?  Is there a clear pattern of which heads should and should not be stripped from `Missing[]`?

Comment: @MrWizard I agree you answered OP's question. I just thought that I should point out the dangers of what OP is trying to do. I can sum up my warning as follows: in a symbolic language, there is only a fuzzy line between a function and a data structure; propagating Missing might be sensible for a function, but not for a data structure. As for how to distinguish the two, I absolutely agree that it would be good to have something like `$InertHeads`, which includes things like List and Association. A (buggy) first stab can be found in ``GeneralUtilities`Predicates`PackagePrivate`$SimpleHeads``

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it seems a reasonable approach - lacking a WRI solution that doens't require Unprotect - I'll test along w Taliesin's suggestions, possibly with an update to my Q... Congrats on the 5-digit rep, well deserved.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon, the application area here is data analysis where Missing[] data will at least initially be undifferentiated, and to be as unobtrusive as possible. Currently, most Dataset computations throw *highly opaque* Failures including on unevaluated expressions wrapped around Missing[].

Comment: A usable compromised based on `UpValues` is to make only a specific "reason" invariant:  `Missing /: _[Missing["."]] := Missing["."]`

Comment: @alancalvitti I'd very much appreciate it if you collect one or two examples of Dataset being unhelpful around Failures so I can fix them :)

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon, I said opaque. The main problem is that Failure messages, besides being often Microsoft-cryptic, "replace" the entire Dataset even if an operator works correctly on most data elements/parts, or leave some parts of Dataset invariant. This deprives users of context and requires unnecesary investigation to localize the issue. Why not return the entire dataset with specific parts unevaluated? Sure I can provide examples. Here or to WRI tech support?

Comment: @alancalvitti I agree that `Failure`s could have more information about exactly where they happened. But have you looked at the `FailureAction` option? With the value `"Encapsulate"` it does exactly what you want. It also supports other useful behavior. It is technically an option to `Query`, so you would write `Query[..., FailureAction -> ...] @ dataset`, but you can use it more concisely by writing `ds[..., FailureAction -> ...]` (recall that `ds[...]` is equivalent to `Query[...] @ ds`).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I may have accepted this too soon. The desired result for `Plus[1, Missing[], 2]` is again `Missing[]` not `3 + Missing[]`.  Is it possible to modify your approach? Is `_[___,m_Missing[],___] ^:=m` reasonable?

Comment: @alancalvitti Do you really mean `m_Missing[]` as that should match `Missing["foo"][]` rather than simply `Missing[]` or `Missing["foo"]`.  Anyway I cannot see why the more general pattern wouldn't work, but it would be even more likely to create bugs or crashes, without additional pattern constraints, e.g. ``Global` `` context etc.

Answer (score 6):

Especially important are making `Missing` 'invariant' for things like `Map` and `Select`, instead of having the contents of the Missing object be mapped or selected. This is a kind of monad, to those who are into that kind of thing.

We need to tackle this at a language level, perhaps with an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be done if we stick to *numeric* functions. This is the solution that worked for me:

```
Missing /: 
  f_Symbol[___, m_Missing, ___] /; MemberQ[Attributes[f], NumericFunction] :=
   m;
```

This way, expressions like  `Missing[...] - Missing[...]` or `a Exp[b + Missing[...]]` evaluate to `Missing[...]` (even for symbolic `a`, `b`). Expressions like `{1, 2, 3, Missing[...]}` are left intact.

Another solution is to use  `Indeterminate` in the place of `Missing[...]`.